# Xcode open link with UIAlert button "in one time code"

Tags: xcode, button, hyperlink, uialertview

I work on an update of one of my iPhone App.
I need to do something I never do...

I want to launch an URL in Safari browser with an UIAlert "in one time code".

Let me explain a little more :
If I want launch Safari with an UIAlert, I can write easily something like :

```
- (void)OpenApple:(id)sender {

    UIAlertView *URLApple = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"Open Apple",@"Open") message: NSLocalizedString(@"Want you open Apple",@"Apple") delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"No", @"close") otherButtonTitles: NSLocalizedString(@"Yes", @"yes"), nil];
    alertView.tag = TAG_URL;
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        if ( alertView.tag == TAG_URL ) {
        NSLog(@"Clicked button index 0");
        // Do nothing
        }} else {
        if ( alertView.tag == TAG_URL ){
        NSLog(@"Clicked button index other than 0");
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: NSLocalizedString(@"http://www.apple.com", @"URLApple")];
            if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}}}}
```

But now, I want to do "this 2 (void) in one time"...

In a few words, I need to open external URL in the first part of my above excerpt.

It's a bit like:

"UIAlertView *URLApple = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"Open Apple",@"Open") message: NSLocalizedString(@"Want you open Apple",@"Apple") delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"No", @"close") otherButtonTitles: NSLocalizedString(@"Yes", @"yes"), nil]; alertView.tag = TAG_URL; [alertView show]; [alertView release];

**if @"yes" = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]**}"

The other hand, I can't write something like :
-(void) alertView: (UIAlertView *)alert1: clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://apple.com"]];

Too easy... 
**I must need something that starts with the first part of the code that I used as an example**  **(** (void)OpenApple:(id)sender {

UIAlertView *URLApple = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"Open Apple",@"Open") message: NSLocalizedString(@"Want you open Apple",@"Apple") delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"No", @"close") otherButtonTitles: NSLocalizedString(@"Yes", @"yes"), nil]; alertView.tag = TAG_URL; [alertView show]; [alertView release]; } **)**.

**This first part of code must contain the URL I have to open...**

I have to write the code this way because the URL I need to open (which is not the URL of the website...) can in no case be sent to another part of my code (another "-(void)", in sum). The alert, the alert button that triggers the opening URL & the URL itself must be located in the same part of my code.

Is it possible?
You food for thought on this?

In advance, thank you to who can help me.

Best regards,
CCC.